# declare "procedure" in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm new to MATLAB, and I couldn't seem to find this in the documentation.
I know how to declare a function that returns something, but how do I declare a function that does NOT return anything - or a procedure, as some people call it?

I can do something like this but I was wondering if there's a better way:

```
function ret = myProcedure()
   %do stuff

   ret = 0; %random var; has no meaning

end
```

EDIT 1: I'm using MATLAB R2014b

Comment: Just make a function with no output arguments. Maybe you can give some code that shows your problem better?

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions: you question appear to have nothing to do with building GUIs in Matlab, so I removed the [matlab-guide] tag.

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove `ret` from your `function` declaration and replace it with a set of empty braces (`[]`):

```
function [] = myProcedure()
   %do stuff           

end
```

I've always done it this way because I'm explicitly telling MATLAB that I am returning nothing, which is symbolized by the empty array `[]`.  This is a stylistic choice and you don't have to follow it.

What is probably cleaner, and an alternative way is to do what David suggests and just do:

```
function myProcedure
    %do stuff

end
```

Comment: Just `function myProcedure` is adequate